# 'view has effective visibility=VISIBLE' doesn't match the selected view. Espresso error

Tags: android, android-espresso

Trying to verify my snack bar been shown

Calling

```
onView(withText(R.string.checkout_device_error))
        .check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)))
```

Due to the debugger everything goes fine and method make it visible but test fail

```
 'view has effective visibility=VISIBLE' doesn't match the selected view.
    Expected: view has effective visibility=VISIBLE
    Got: "MaterialTextView{id=2131362495, res-name=ribbon_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@7c97dc7f, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=Invalid username and or password., input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

Comment: Do you get the same with `onView(withText(R.string.checkout_device_error))
                .check(matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))` .. probably some ancestor views are GONE/INVISIBLE .. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238033/espresso-witheffectivevisibility-vs-isdisplayed) for more detail

Comment: @Zain yes the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the exact failure you're getting as you mentioned that the failure logs you received in the Debugging State. However if this the error that you're getting, then the catch is the container `View` of `checkout_device_error` string is **not yet visible** when you're trying to assert it's visibility. Let's take a look at your log -

```
visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0,  x=0.0, y=0.0
```

If you see, the `MaterialTextView` has visibility `VISIBLE` but it's `height` and `width` is `0` and also the `x` `y` coordinates are also `0`. This mean that in the parent container, the `MaterialTextView` has visibility `VISIBLE`. However, the parent container might not be visible.

I had faced the same issue where I had a `RatingBar` with visibility `VISIBLE` inside a `ConstraintLayout` which has initial visibility `GONE`. When I tried to validate the visibility of the `RatingBar`, it failed giving the same error. This won't happen if your parent view remains in `INVISIBLE` / `GONE` state during your validation but if the Parent View is transitioning the Visibility state and your Validation call happens simultaneously, then this issue arises. I fixed this issue by giving a delay to properly finish the Parent View's transition and then initiating the Visibility validation. I will recommend you to do the same and give some delay in order to make the `Snackbar` appear completely.